# Determining the type of singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification, laurent-series, singularity

> Determine the type of singularities of
>   $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)\cot(\pi/z)}\tag{1}$$

We first rewrite the function:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)\cot(\pi/z)}=\frac{\sin(\pi/z)}{(z-1)\cos(\pi/z)} \tag{2}$$

Now we solve
$$(z-1)\cos(\pi/z)\overset{!}{=}0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \hat{z}=1, \ z_k=\frac{2}{1+2k}, \quad k\in\mathbb Z \tag{3}$$

At first, $\hat{z}=1$ introduces a simple pole but then we see that $\sin(\pi/\hat{z})=0$. So we better check the limit there:

$$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{\sin(\pi/z)}{(z-1)\cos(\pi/z)}\overset{hopital}{=}\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{\cos(\pi/z)\pi}{\cos(\pi/z)-(z-1)\sin(\pi/z)}=\pi\tag{4}$$

So since that limit exists, we just found a continuation of the function at the problem point $\hat{z}=1$. So we can conclude:

$\hat{z}=1$ is a removable singularity.

After seeing that $\sin(\pi/z)$ has a root at $\hat{z}=1$ we could have also just argued that the simple pole introduced by $(1-z)$ woudl have order 1 and since the first derivative of $\sin(\pi/z)$ doesn't have a root at $\hat{z}=1$ anymore, we would have an "order" or $1-1=0$, which basically is a removable singularity.

**Question:** Where does this argumentation exactly come from?

Now for $z=0$ we have a non-isolated singularity, since trigonometric functions with an argument of the type $1/z$ go crazy there.

We know the Taylor series: $\cos(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}$ so we get $$\cos(1/z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}\tag{5}$$

So we see, for $z_k$ we get simple poles of order 1.

Anything specifically wrong here?

Comment: Are you also an ITET student at the ETHZ in Zurich ?                                                 Bist du auch ITET student an der ETHZ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin\left(\frac\pi z\right)$ has a simple zero at $z=1$ and $\cos\left(\frac\pi z\right)$ has not zero there,$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi z\right)}{(z-1)\cos\left(\frac\pi z\right)}$$has a removable singularity at $z=1$ (the simple zero in the numerator cancels the simple zero in the denominator). It's as simple as that.

Comment: But where exactly does that come from? Is it just because of the Taylor series?

Comment: Yes. If $1$ is a simple zero of $f$ and it is not a zero of $g$ and if the Taylor series of $f$ and $g$ centered at $1$ are $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z-1)^n$ respectively, then$$\frac{f(z)}{(z-1)g(z)}=\frac{a_1(z-1)+a_2(z-1)^2+\cdots}{b_0(z-1)+b_1(z-1)^2+\cdots}=\frac{a_1+a_2(z-1)+\cdots}{b_0+b_1(z-1)+\cdots}$$and therefore$$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{a_0}{b_1}.$$

Comment: Thanks - although isn't what I wrote in (5) wrong?

Comment: Yes, I missed that. It should be$$\cos\left(\frac1z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{-2n}.$$

Comment: so that means that the Laurent series of $\cos(1/z)$ has a infinite principal part, right? But since it's in the denominator, we still have a simple pole of order one?

Comment: No. We have an essential singularity.

Comment: The solution says they are simple poles though. Since $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)\cot(\pi/z)}=\frac{\tan(\pi/z)}{z-1}$$ so we have singularities at $z'_k=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, k=0,1,..$ which are poles since $\lim_{z\to z'_k}tan(z)=\infty$. The order is 1 because $$\tan(z)=\frac{-1}{z-z'}+O((z-z'_k)^1)$$ I don't see their argument though. Is it wrong?

Comment: The function $\cos\left(\frac\pi z\right)$ has a simple pole at $1$ and an essential singularity at $0$: SInce you computed the Laurent series centered at $0$, I assumed that, when you asked what type of singularity it was, you meant the point $0$.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. I actually meant every possible singularity. That $z=0$ is essential, that's clear. But What confused me is how exactly I can conclude that the others are simple poles. Does your argument still hold?

Comment: The function $\frac1{(z-1)\cos\left(\frac\pi z\right)}$ has a simple pole at $1$ because $(z-1)\cos\left(\frac\pi z\right)$ has a simple zero there.

Comment: okay thanks a lot!